# How do I remove attachments from my weapon?

Tags: vive, h3vr

I cannot figure out how to remove attachments from any weapon in Hot Dogs, Horseshoes, and Handgrenades. 
Whenever I put an attachment (such as a scope) on a firearm with a Picatinny rail, I don't know how to remove it.

Is it a button combination on the HTC Vive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On weapons that have a removable attachment mounted, follow this process (for the HTC Vive):

1. Grab the attachment with a free hand with the trigger button.
2. Click down on the touchpad to unlock it, you will hear a click.
3. Lift your hand off of the weapon and you will be holding the attachment.

You can also do this process if you are not directly holding the weapon.